# Should I use "as" or "when"?

Tags: grammar, difference, conjunctions

Should I use "as" or "when" in the sentence below? And if both are OK, what is the difference?

Making his way down the hallway, Kurt suddenly stops as/when he spots the name 'Paul Davis' on a door.

(Don't know if it changes anything, but Kurt wasn't looking for Paul Davis's office, he just came by and incidentally recognized the name on the door.)

Comment: You can use either. Literally, using _as_ suggests that Kurt stops while still in the act of reading the name, but in practice I can't see any difference in the meaning.

Comment: I agree with Kate. No difference.